# T-Test on one DataFrame with Groups from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

**The Goal:**

Perform t-test on DataFrame (df_rna) using group found in another DataFrame (df_cnv).  Reduce the test DataFrame (df_rna) the row indices with the most significant scores from the t-test.

**Code Sample:**

```
# Dataframe (df_cnv) that forms groups of columns (cells) either\ belonging to True or False for t-test.
cnv = {'gene': ['x','y','z','n'],
        'cell_a': [0,-1,0,-1],
        'cell_b': [0,-1,-1,-1],
        'cell_c': [-1,0,-1,0],
        'cell_d': [-1,0,-1,0],
        'cell_e': [-1,0,0,0]
       }
df_cnv = pd.DataFrame(cnv)
df_cnv.set_index('gene', inplace=True)
cnv_mask = df_cnv < 0
cnv_mask  # True values are negative (gene loss is True)
```

[image: cnv_mask masked for negative values]

```
# DataFrame for t-test and subsequent reduction to most significant rows
 rna = {'gene': ['x','y','z','n'],
            'cell_a': [1, 5, 8,9],
            'cell_b': [8, 5, 4,9],
            'cell_c': [8, 6, 1,1],
            'cell_d': [1, 2, 7,1],
            'cell_e': [5, 7, 9,1],
           }
    df_rna = pd.DataFrame(rna)
    df_rna.set_index('gene')
```

[image: df_rna]

```
# Manually computed T-Tests, save results in DataFrame df_report
x = scipy.stats.ttest_ind([8,1,5],[1,8])
y = scipy.stats.ttest_ind([5,5], [6,2,7])
z = scipy.stats.ttest_ind([4,1,7], [8,9])
n = scipy.stats.ttest_ind([9,9], [1,1,1])

tStat = [gene.statistic for gene in [x,y,z,n]]
pVal = [gene.pvalue for gene in [x,y,z,n]]

report = {'gene':['x','y','z','n'],
         't_stat':tStat,
         'p_val':pVal}
df_report = pd.DataFrame(report)
df_report.set_index('gene', inplace=True)
```

[image: df_report from t-test]

```
# Create reduced version of test DataFrame (df_rna) to contain only rows (genes
df_pass = df_report.loc[df_report['p_val'] < 0.05]
passed_genes = set(df_pass.index)
passed_genes

df_rna_pass = df_rna.loc[df_rna['gene'].isin(passed_genes)]
df_rna_pass.set_index('gene')
```

[image: df_rna_pass reduced df_rna DataFrame with only rows with p_val < 0.05]

**The Question:**

Manually setting the t-test groups is not feasible for my large dataset.  How do I compute all the t-test statistics across the whole DataFrame `df_rna` when the groups of cells being either True and False changes for every row?

**Mystery Hang:** (happens if your don't cache the results of `rnadf_all[~cnv_mask]`)

```
C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:82: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  warnings.warn("Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice", RuntimeWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ccabe33b2612> in <module>()
     34 
     35 for r in rnadf_all[cnv_mask].iterrows():
---> 36     df_report.at[r[0], 't_stat'], df_report.at[r[0], 'p_val'] = scipy.stats.ttest_ind(r[1].dropna(), rnadf_all[~cnv_mask].loc[r[0]].dropna())
     37 
     38 df_pass = df_report.loc[df_report['p_val'] < 0.05]

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1963             return self._getitem_array(key)
   1964         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
-> 1965             return self._getitem_frame(key)
   1966         elif is_mi_columns:
   1967             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_frame(self, key)
   2036         if key.values.dtype != np.bool_:
   2037             raise ValueError('Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only')
-> 2038         return self.where(key)
   2039 
   2040     def query(self, expr, **kwargs):

C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, try_cast, raise_on_error)
   3931         # try to align
   3932         try_quick = True
-> 3933         if hasattr(other, 'align'):
   3934 
   3935             # align with me

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 from scipy import stats

 # Create empty DF for t-test results
 df_report = pd.DataFrame(index=df_rna.index, columns=['p_val', 't_stat'])

 not_df_rna = df_rna[~cnv_mask]

 # Iterate through df_rna rows, apply mask, drop NaN values, run ttest_ind and save result to df_report
 for r in df_rna[cnv_mask].iterrows():
     df_report.at[r[0], 't_stat'], df_report.at[r[0], 'p_val'] = stats.ttest_ind(r[1].dropna(), not_df_rna.loc[r[0]].dropna())
```

Result:

```
df_report

         p_val     t_stat
gene                     
x     0.966863  0.0450988
y            1          0
z     0.141358   -1.98508
n            0        inf
```

Comment: this solution hangs, and throws a warning `C:\Users\test\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:82: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  warnings.warn("Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice", RuntimeWarning)`.  i've never seen this before.  Is this a numpy issue?

Comment: I didn't notice that you have posted Traceback. Can you check, how much time does it take to apply ~cnv_mask to rnadf_all: rnadf_all[~cnv_mask]? With big DataFrame my solution is not optimal, as this will be done on every iteration of the loop. So it's better to do this once before the loop and cache the result: not_rnadf_all = rnadf_all[~cnv_mask]; then in the loop replace rnadf_all[~cnv_mask].loc[r[0]].dropna() with not_rnadf_all.loc[r[0]].dropna()

Comment: I submitted each example (optimal and less optimal) onto our school's compute cluster 15 hours ago.  The optimal one finished (with what appears to be reasonable results) in 00:02:01 CPU time with max vmem at 5.174G.  The less optimal one still appears to be running...

Comment: The suboptimal solution finished with 15:09:03 CPU time with max vmem at 5.112G.  I'll edit your solution to reflect the best version.  Thanks again.

Comment: I should have thought of it when I saw your comment about 20000 rows in your DF. It's not a problem for 5x4 matrix with your sample data, but if filtering whole DF with cnv_mask takes for example 4,5 seconds, then with 20000 rows we will spend 15 hours doing that in a loop for every row separately. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by transposing the two DFs, and setting up a new DF for the t-test results:

```
cnv_mask_t = cnv_mask.transpose()
df_rna_t = df_rna.transpose()
df_tres = pd.dataframe(index=df_rna.index, columns=['pval', 'stat'])
```

Then you can iterate over the genes, which are now columns, and filter for values in which the mask contains True:

```
for gene in df_rna_t:
    col_mask = cnv_mask_t[gene]
    tres = scipy.stats.ttest_ind(df_rna_t[gene][col_mask], df_rna_t[gene][~col_mask])
    df_tres.loc[gene] = [tres.pvalue, tres.statistic]
```

I assume you can take it from here.

Comment: P.S. I'm currently on mobile so I couldn't test the code. Let me know if you need any more help and I'll be sure to look into it when I get to a computer.

Comment: Very clean and very clear python.  The transpose is the only issue, since I'm working with multiple dataframes of about 3000 col by 20,000 rows.  Otherwise very easy to understand, but what is the role of the tilde in `[~col_mask]`?

Comment: It negates the Boolean vector, allowing the selection of all of the cells in which the mask is False.

Comment: @Thomas Matthew, if you want to get rid of transposition, see my answer.